# Inkscape insert text after importing pdf

Tags: inkscape

I am trying to edit text from a PDF file - but when I enter the new text, it jumbles it up. What do I need to do to fix this? For instance, below I wanted to insert Hourly into 'Percent Maximum Concentration`.

[image]

The path for the text object has:

```
  <g
         id="g10872">
        <g
           clip-path="url(#clipPath10878)"
           id="g10874">
          <text
             id="text10882"
             style="font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:11px;font-family:Helvetica;-inkscape-font-specification:Helvetica;writing-mode:lr-tb;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
             transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,115.27,141.72)">
            <tspan
               id="tspan10880"
               sodipodi:role="line"
               y="0"
               x="0 6.7870002 12.903 16.566 22.066 28.181999 34.298 37.355999 40.414001 49.577 55.693001 61.193001 63.634998 72.688004 78.804001 87.967003 91.025002 98.967003 105.083 111.199 116.699 122.815 128.931 131.989 135.54201 141.658 144.716 147.158 153.274">Percent Maximum Concentration</tspan>
          </text>
```

Comment: I don't know Inkscape but I know that .PDFs don't even play well with other adobe products. Try editing it with acrobat pro.

Comment: The text might not be properly editable. It sometimes depends on how the PDF was made.  You could simply delete the whole line of text and add a new line of text to replace it.

Comment: Can you mark the text, and post the XML (4th Button from the right)?

Comment: @user unknown - Not sure how to export the XML - I can view it on the tree using a button, but there doesn't seem to be a way to move it out of the viewer.

Comment: You can read, which unique id is given, and then open the SVG in a Texteditor and copy the section from there.

Comment: Ok revising question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To restore normal editing functionality of text in `tspan` element, set the x-attribute of the `tspan` element to `0`:

```
<tspan
      id="tspan10880"
      sodipodi:role="line"
      y="0"
      x="0">Percent Maximum Concentration</tspan>
```

[image: Pdf text import - restore editing]

- Select `internal importer` during the import
- Edit the xml using the Inkscape XML Editor `Edit > XML Editor`
- Tested with inkscape 0.92.2

Comment: I just tested it and it works perfectly. Thank you for your kind help @FWrnr.

Answer (score 3):

There was a nice and much simpler solution over the problem which was reported here: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/275184 by user Krzysztof Kosinski

1. Select the text block in the imported PDF.
2. Go to the `Text` menu and then select `Remove Manual Kerns`

Worked as a charm for me!

To generalize it to all text blocks in a file:

1. Go to top `Edit` menu
2. Choose `Select Same` -> `Object Type`

Then you can repeat the above-mentioned procedure with `Edit` > `Remove Manual Kerns`.